# Create SQL table based on class that has collection of self (VB.net / C#)

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to create a table in SQL database

As a noob in SQL, what my struggle is having a collection of my class, and how I go about creating Table and read from it.

```vb
Public Class MyFeatureVM
   
    Private _Name As String = String.Empty
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value        
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _DisplayName As String = String.Empty
    Public Property DisplayName() As String
        Get
            Return _DisplayName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _DisplayName = value        
        End Set
    End Property
   
    Private _items As Collection(Of MyFeatureVM)
    Public Property items() As Collection(Of MyFeatureVM)
        Get
            Return _items
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Collection(Of MyFeatureVM))
            _items = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

SQL statement:

```vb
Dim stMYFeatureTable = "CREATE TABLE dbo.MY_FEATURE (" &
    "ConfigItem VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " &
    "Name  VARCHAR(256), " &
    "DisplayName  VARCHAR(256), " &
    ........
    ") "
```

PS: hopefully subject is not misleading

Answer (score 0):

Think you're actually got two questions here.  First one is How to create the table. I will preface this by saying, cyclic relationships can be quite a headache, I would really only go down this route if there is no other option.  And I'm making an assumption that you're using SQL Server, you weren't clear which flavor of SQL.

First thing to consider, how many levels of recursion is valid?

Create table script will look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[My_Feature](
    [ConfigItem] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [DisplayName] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [ParentConfigItem] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_My_Feature] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ConfigItem] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[My_Feature]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_My_Feature_My_Feature] FOREIGN KEY([ParentConfigItem])
REFERENCES [dbo].[My_Feature] ([ConfigItem])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[My_Feature] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_My_Feature_My_Feature]
GO
```

Next, I would do something with the items property getter:

```
Private _items As Collection(Of MyFeatureVM)
Public Property items() As Collection(Of MyFeatureVM)
    Get
        if (_items = Nothing) then
            _items = 'Query DB for collection where PartentConfigItem = _configItem
        End if
        Return _items
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Collection(Of MyFeatureVM))
        _items = value
    End Set
End Property
```

This of course assumes that you've got a property for _configItem which isn't specified in your Class Def above